# Slot game, how to print "win" or "lose" in Paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to Jquery, How do I make it so prints "you have won" or " You have lost". I want it to make so if you hit 3 the same fruits it prints that you have won.

```js
 function EZSlots(id,useroptions){
 var that = this; //keep reference to function for use in callbacks
 //set some variables from the options, or with defaults.
 var options = useroptions ? useroptions : {};
 this.reelCount = options.reelCount ? options.reelCount : 3; //how many reels, assume 3 
 this.symbols = options.symbols ? options.symbols : ['A','B','C'];
 this.sameSymbolsEachSlot = true;
 this.startingSet = options.startingSet;
 this.winningSet = options.winningSet;
 this.width = options.width ? options.width : 100;
 this.height = options.width ? options.height : 100;
 this.howManySymbolsToAppend = 20; //how many symbols each spin adds
 this.endingLocation = 7; //location for selected symbol... needs to be a few smaller than howManySymbolsToAppend
 this.time = 500; //time in millis for a spin to take
 this.jqo = $("#"+id); //jquery object reference to main wrapper
 this.jqoSliders = []; //jquery object reference to strips sliding up and down

 //to initialize we construct the correct number of slot windows
 //and then populate each strip once
 this.init = function(){
  this.jqo.addClass("ezslots"); //to get the css goodness
  //figure out if we are using the same of symbols for each window - assume if the first 
  //entry of the symbols is not a string we have an array of arrays
  if(typeof this.symbols[0] != 'string'){
   this.sameSymbolsEachSlot = false;
  }
  //make each slot window
  for(var i = 0; i < this.reelCount; i++){
   var jqoSlider = $('<div class="slider"></div>');
   var jqoWindow = $('<div class="window window_"'+i+'></div>');
   this.scaleJqo(jqoWindow).append(jqoSlider); //make window right size and put slider in it
   this.jqo.append(jqoWindow); //add window to main div
   this.jqoSliders.push(jqoSlider); //keep reference to jqo of slider
   this.addSymbolsToStrip(jqoSlider,i, false, true); //and add the initial set 
  }
 };
 //convenience function since we need to apply width and height to multiple parts
 this.scaleJqo = function(jqo){
  jqo.css("height",this.height+"px").css("width",this.width+"px");
  return jqo;
 }
 //add the various symbols - but take care to possibly add the "winner" as the symbol chosen
 this.addSymbolsToStrip = function(jqoSlider, whichReel, shouldWin, isInitialCall){
  var symbolsToUse = that.sameSymbolsEachSlot ? that.symbols : that.symbols[whichReel];
  var chosen =  shouldWin ? that.winningSet[whichReel] : Math.floor(Math.random()*symbolsToUse.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < that.howManySymbolsToAppend; i++){
   var ctr = (i == that.endingLocation) ? chosen : Math.floor(Math.random()*symbolsToUse.length);
   if(i == 0 && isInitialCall && that.startingSet){
    ctr = that.startingSet[whichReel];
   }
   //we nest "content" inside of "symbol" so we can do vertical and horizontal centering more easily
   var jqoContent = $("<div class='content'>"+symbolsToUse[ctr]+"</div>");
   that.scaleJqo(jqoContent);
   var jqoSymbol = $("<div class='symbol'></div>");
   that.scaleJqo(jqoSymbol);
   jqoSymbol.append(jqoContent);
   jqoSlider.append(jqoSymbol);
  }
  return chosen;
 }
 //to spin, we add symbols to a strip, and then bounce it down
 this.spinOne = function(jqoSlider,whichReel,shouldWin){
  var heightBefore = parseInt(jqoSlider.css("height"), 10); 
  var chosen = that.addSymbolsToStrip(jqoSlider,whichReel,shouldWin);
  var marginTop = -(heightBefore + ((that.endingLocation) * that.height));
  jqoSlider.stop(true,true).animate(
   {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
   {'duration' : that.time + Math.round(Math.random()*1000), 'easing' : "easeOutElastic"});
  return chosen;
 }

 this.spinAll = function(shouldWin){
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < that.reelCount; i++){
    results.push(that.spinOne(that.jqoSliders[i],i,shouldWin));
   }
  return results;
 }

 this.init();
 return {
  spin : function(){
   return that.spinAll();
  },
  win : function(){
   return that.spinAll(true);
  }
 }
}
$(function(){
 //setting up some sample set sof things we can make a slot machine of
 var images = ['<img src="images/seven.png">','<img src="images/banana.png">','<img src="images/cherries.png">','<img src="images/lemon.png">','<img src="images/orange.png">','<img src="images/plum.png">','<img src="images/watermelon.png">'];
 //using images instead, and more reels
 var ezslot2 = new EZSlots("ezslots2",{"reelCount":3,"winningSet":[0,0,0],"symbols":images,"height":126,"width":126});
 

 $(document).ready(function() { console.log(ezslot2.spin());});
});
```

I am using template from GitHub that's already made by someone but remaking it into my own needs.

Please be easy on me I'm new to Jquery :)

thank you very much!

Comment: I am getting an error if I try to run your code

Comment: the code requires jquery.easing.1.3.js to work, I can link the whole github here If I am allowed to do so.  The code above is the whole function for slot machine itself nothing else

Comment: @Duxieking Look on google for a jsfiddle that already has jquery.easing running in it. Then pop in your code and it'll make it much easier for us to help out.